# How to split Excel sheet into multiple sheets based on a delimiter value?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to split an Excel sheet into multiple sheets. There are many tables on the sheet I'm trying to split, and they are each separated by "-----", which appears after every table in column A. Does anyone know how to extract the information before and after each "-----" and put it onto a new sheet? I don't mind copying the string onto a new sheet as well. If I have 10 tables on a sheet separated by "-----", I would like 10 sheets, each with a different table.

I unfortunately don't have any code yet, because none of my attempts to extract information between a repeated value have worked. I'd really appreciate ideas, even just for individual steps along the way.

Comment: What attempts have you made? Please show any code/formulas you've tried, and what has/hasn't worked.  You can also use Data --> Text to Columns to separate data based on a delimiter, have you tried that?

Comment: It's not particularly difficult; `startRng= topOfSheet; Loop: nextRng= find-the-pattern starting from startRng, copy the range between startRng and nextRng into new sheet, startRng = nextRng.offset(1)`. Loop continues until pattern not found. Start coding this and when you face any blocking issues paste the code and we will be happy to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. Modify `searchString` as per your requirement. It will not create a new sheet for the fist set of data which means it will create 9 additional sheets and the original sheet will be the 10th sheet

```
Option Explicit

Sub serachAndCopy()
    Dim searchString As String
    searchString = "---"

    Dim lastRow As Integer, i As Integer
    lastRow = 0

    Dim thisSheet As Worksheet
    Set thisSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim sh As Worksheet

    For i = thisSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If (thisSheet.Range("A" & i) = searchString) Then
            If lastRow = 0 Then
                lastRow = i
                Else
                Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                Set sh = ActiveSheet
                thisSheet.Rows(i + 1 & ":" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=sh.Rows("1:1")

                thisSheet.Rows(i + 1 & ":" & lastRow).Delete
                lastRow = i
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow thank you! This did exactly what I needed to. I only started learning VBA a few weeks ago, so I really appreciate the help